# Duplication formula for the general case: $x$-coordinate of $n(x, y)$

Tags: elliptic-curves

The **duplication formula** for an elliptic curve over rationals:
$$y^2 = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$$

for the $x$-coordinate is given by:

$x$-coordinate of $2(x, y)=(x^4-2bx^2-8cx+b^2-4ac)/(4x^3+4ax^2+4bx+4c)$

Here $2(x, y)=(x, y)+(x,y)$ via the group law of addition of two points on the curve.

I am asking if there is a similar formula or a **shape** for the general case: $x$-coordinate of $n(x, y)$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

Can the duplicate formula be understood as an **iterative sequence**, i.e., replacing the $x$ coordinate of  $n(x,y)$ by the $x$ coordinate of $(n+1) (x,y)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $E$ is an elliptic curve, $P=(x,y)$ is a point on $E$, and $n\geq 1$, the coordinates of the point $Q=nP$ are given by the division polynomials 
$$nP = \left(\frac{\phi_n(x)}{\psi^2_n(x)},\frac{\omega_n(x,y)}{\psi^3_n(x,y)}\right).$$
The definition of the division polynomials can be found in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials), for example. These polynomials are defined recursively, so one can compute them easily (but they get very large as $n$ grows).